# Get JSON List Tree Value

Tags: jquery, json

```
{ "httpCode": "200",
  "status": "success",
  "message": "SuccessFully Listed",
  "details": {"result": [{"Id": 1,"Key": "B33C78A0-C598-4071-863B-EF6B6978F790","Name": "Windows","ShortName": "Win"}]}}
```

this is my Json Result i need Get **result** List. How to Get That Result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If array format you can parse json

```
var det = JSON.parse('{ "httpCode": "200",
  "status": "success",
  "message": "SuccessFully Listed",
  "details": {"result": [{"Id": 1,"Key": "B33C78A0-C598-4071-863B-EF6B6978F790","Name": "Windows","ShortName": "Win"}]}}');

alert(det['details']['result']);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the dot operator

```
var obj = { "httpCode": "200",
  "status": "success",
  "message": "SuccessFully Listed",
  "details": {"result": [{"Id": 1,"Key": "B33C78A0-C598-4071-863B-EF6B6978F790","Name": "Windows","ShortName": "Win"}]}}

console.log(obj.details.result[0].Name)
```